# MongoDB java driver bulk update vs regular update performance

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am using MongoDB java driver in my application.

In a specific use case, I had to update huge number of records in a collection. I found that using MongoDb Java Driver's `BulkUpdate` API had far worse performance as compared to regular update. This is really strange, I thought bulk update method was supposed increase performance.

Here are specific details - 
Collection had `270k records`. There were around `17k update` statements to be executed. Database is locally installed.

**Bulk Update Code**

```
public void scramble(String collectionName, String fieldName) {
    final List<String> distinctValues = getDistinctValues(collectionName, fieldName);
    final BulkWriteOperation bulk = mongoDb.getCollection(collectionName).initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    for (final String actualValue : distinctValues) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(actualValue)) {
            final String scrambledValue = getScrambledValue(actualValue);
            update(fieldName, actualValue, scrambledValue, bulk);
        }
    }
    bulk.execute();
}

protected void update(String fieldName, String actualValue, String scrambledValue, BulkWriteOperation bulk) {
    final DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject(fieldName, actualValue);
    final DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject(fieldName, scrambledValue));
    bulk.find(searchQuery).update(updateQuery);
}
```

**Regular Update Code**

```
public void scramble(String collectionName, String fieldName) {
    final List<String> distinctValues = getDistinctValues(collectionName, fieldName);
    for (final String actualValue : distinctValues) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(actualValue)) {
            final String scrambledValue = getScrambledValue(actualValue);
            update(collectionName, fieldName, actualValue, scrambledValue);
        }
    }
}

protected void update(String collectionName, String fieldName, String actualValue, String scrambledValue) {
    final DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject(fieldName, actualValue);
    final DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject(fieldName, scrambledValue));
    mongoDb.getCollection(collectionName).update(searchQuery, updateQuery);
}
```

Bulk Update API code took around `1.5 hrs` and regular update took `2-3 mins`.
Can someone please explain this behavior.

Comment: the collection you are updating is indexed?

Comment: no, the collection is not indexed

Comment: Can you do that now? You are reading the data before updating, as it is not indexed, its taking long time. Index the collection and give a try! Hopefully, it should work better than usual update. All the best!

Comment: Collection not being indexed should have the same effect on both cases.

Comment: yeah.. you are right. But you are not searching in the regular update. In Bulk update case, you are searching and updating. As your collection is not indexed, it is scanning the whole collection and updating it. You can check the performance with explain command.

Comment: Help me understand this  - you are saying in bulk update it searches(executes the `find` part) and hence its slow. But both the updates have find part(when clause), and I as understand, this find part will be executed in both the cases, then where does the difference comes from ?